# Values of dictionary = sum of 2dlist at i

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following 2d list and dictionary:

```
List2d = [['1', '55', '32', '667' ],

         ['43', '76', '55', '100'],

         ['23', '70', '15', '300']] 

dictionary = {'New York':0, "London": 0, "Tokyo": 0, "Toronto": 0 }
```

How do I replace all the values of the dictionary with sums of the columns in List2d? So dictionary will look like this:

```
dictionary= {'New York' : 67, 'London': 201, 'Tokyo': 102, 'Toronto': 1067}

#67 comes from adding up first column (1+43+23) in 'List2d'

#201 comes from adding up second column (55+76+70) in 'List2d'

#102 comes from adding up third column (32+55+15) in 'List2d'

#1067 comes from adding up fourth column (667+100+300) in 'List2d'
```

Comment: How do you know how to match dictionary keys to column index? The dict is unordered.

Comment: I'm trying to have it so whatever the first key in the dictionary is the value = sum of first column second key in dictionary value = sum of second column etc

Answer (score 0):

### Since Python 3.7, keys in dict are ordered.

You can use enumerate in order to keep track of the position of the element in the dict while iterating over it. Then, you use the `i` as an index on each row of the 2d list, convert each value to int and do a sum of the result.

```py
List2d = [['1', '55', '32', '667' ],
         ['43', '76', '55', '100'],
         ['23', '70', '15', '300']] 

dictionary = {'New York':0, "London": 0, "Tokyo": 0, "Toronto": 0 }

for i, city in enumerate(dictionary.keys()):
    dictionary[city] = sum(int(row[i]) for row in List2d)

print(dictionary)
# {'New York': 67, 'London': 201, 'Tokyo': 102, 'Toronto': 1067}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use pandas

```
#!pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(List2d, columns=dictionary.keys()).astype(int).sum(axis=0).to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'New York': 67, 'London': 201, 'Tokyo': 102, 'Toronto': 1067}
```